# docker compose up received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to create a nodejs docker app using image node:16.13.1. (I have tried to use other version).
There is slow network at my location. Every time I tried to run `sudo docker-compose up -d` , it took longer time to download one large size intermediate container/image. Till that time, one other image does 3 retries to download, and then suddenly command fails with below error.

received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable

```
Building node-app
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.556MB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:16.13.1
16.13.1: Pulling from library/node
9b99af5931b3: Pull complete
b6013b3e77fe: Downloading [=============================================>     ]  7.097MB/7.834MB
bbced17b6899: Download complete
8b609dabefa8: Download complete
50544bfef33d: Downloading [=================================================> ]    **189MB/192.4MB**
fea3f8b8e075: Download complete
c81dbcaf60d9: Download complete
7b0e069b3bda: Downloading
29ac9271f536: Waiting
received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable
ERROR: Service 'node-app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Sometimes it prints connection reset by peer before 503 error.

`read tcp <my-ip>:36140->104.18.122.25:443: read: connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a docker instability of some restriction of your network (i test it here at 2 computers), you can also try to flush DNS from your computer, this DNS error already occurs in docker according this discussion https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-pull-503-service-unavailabl/2401

Comment: Actually it was issue of access in Proxy server. Where some docker hub URLs were not allowed at proxy server. However your analysis was helpful. So marking this as an answer. @Gabriel Vieira